# C++ Constructor coding errors

Tags: c++, constructor

I just stumbled across this bug in some legacy code:

```
class MyAPIHandler
{
    private:
     int handle;
    public:
    void MyApiHandler()  // default constructor
    {
        handle = 42;
    };
};
```

It compiles fine, with no warnings - but the behaviour wasn't what I intended, because the constructor name is misspelt. This by itself would have produced a warning about "function does not return a value", but I guess I was on autopilot and added a "void" return type to 'fix' this.

Now, the bugfix was easy, but my question is this:-

What techniques could I use to prevent this type of bug recurring?

Some languages require an explicit "constructor" keyword, which should make this problem obvious. Unit testing, obviously should also have caught it. What else can I do?

Comment: Constructors are distinguishable by not having a return type.
What would a "constructor" keyword give you? If you accidentally gave it a return type, you would just as easily omit the constructor keyword.
The absence of a return type *is* your keyword.

Comment: @jaff - in C++, if the return type is omitted on a function it defaults to int. C compatability bites us in the butt again.

Comment: *sigh*. This is why proper languages are not case-sensitive.

Comment: @Roddy: default ints are only in C, NOT in C++. This is one point where C++ breaks compatibility with C.

Comment: @Jasper - looks like my compiler has a bug then. I'll dig deeper.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you always use initialiser lists in your constructors:

```
MyApiHandler()  // default constructor
: handle(42)
{
}
```

the misnamed constructor bug would be even more unlikely, and it's better [style](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10) anyway.

**Edit**: thanks to commenter for the link

Comment: "Its better style anyway" Here's the argument for this:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6

Answer (score 2):

Code review?  Unit test, as you mention is good too.  Code coverage.  Many of the usual tools for finding bugs could find this.

Answer (score 2):

Besides being careful or having code reviews, there's not a lot you *can* do.

You can make a checklist for writing new classes with topics like:

- Copy-paste the class name to be used as the first constructor.
- If you implement the copy constructor, implement the destructor and the copy assignment operator (the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).
- Take care with single-argument constructors or constructors with default arguments - consider making them explicit

These are constructor-related points, the whole checklist could be longer.  After a while you'll start doing things like this automatically.

Personally, I think Unit Testing is the best answer to avoid your specific problem, as you already mentioned.

**EDIT:** Added idea from comments:
In some development environments you could use code templates or macros to generate a correct class skeleton for you.  This is a real "programmer's solution" - automating everything that can be automated to avoid errors.

Comment: Actually, the copy/paste thing brings up something I hadn't thought of - Code Templates. My IDE has the ability to use code templates, so my new class template could automatically have a correctly named constructor/destructors

Comment: That's a good idea actually - should be added to the definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be much of a problem. Constructors don't have return values (not even void), so the compiler should be able to tell whether something is meant to be a constructor or a member function, and let you know if there's a problem. Obviously someone saw the compiler's error on that and chose the wrong solution (adding a return type instead of correcting the spelling). (EDIT: Sorry, didn't realize that you'd done that yourself.)

Personally, I always put the constructor(s) near the beginning of the the class's public section (before any member functions, but after public type definitions and constants), so a problem like that would be pretty obvious to me on re-reading the code. But conventions differ on that.

Comment: The author indicated that he was "on autopilot" when he got the compiler warning that the method did not have a return type, and instead of correcting the spelling he added a return type.

Comment: Oops... I thought he said it was legacy code, so I assumed that it was from the original author. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake... it *is* legacy code, but he made that modification himself.

Comment: I should clarify: The original code was mine, but from quite a few years back... And my compiler gave no warning or error about the missing return type - just a warning about not returning a value from a function...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that PC Lint, a static code analysis tool, would have spotted this error.  It isn't free but it is very, very good.  Worth a look:

http://www.gimpel.com/

Comment: I meant to write 'would've' which is pronounced 'would of'.  :)

Answer (score 1):

### I believe you should not think too much about this issue

It happens for constructors, but also for any other method, or even function. For example:

```
class MyBase
{
   // etc.
   virtual void doSomething() ;
} ;

class MyDerived : public MyBase
{
   // etc.
   virtual void DoSomething() ;
} ;
```

Or:

```
bool isOk(int value) { /* etc. */ }
bool isOK(double value) { /* etc. */ }

void doSomething(int value)
{
   if(isOK(value)) // isOK(double) will be called
   {
      // Etc.
   }
}
```

And this is not only a problem of character case. This kind of error happens. IDE helpers like autocompletion can help somewhat, as could a good unit-testing code (something covering all methods of a class), but I don't believe the compiler alone could protect against this kind of developer mistyping even with additionnal keywords.

### What about CONSTRUCTOR?

As for the CONSTRUCTOR define mentionned before me, this is a bad idea IMHO:

It will help as much as a comment (and so, why not use /* CONSTRUCTOR */ instead?), and if someone thought about using the word CONSTRUCTOR as a define symbol, then you can bet someone else will have the same idea in some header you include but don't own, and that it will break your code...

Comment: I'd forgotten that *virtual* functions could give the same grief - thanks!

Comment: And also with function overloading... ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If the member variable is not going to change, declare it const and the compiler will force you to use an initialiser list, which in this case would force you to detect your error (because it won't compile).

Comment: This works but only for types without a user-defined default constructor.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. THanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do a

```
#define CONSTRUCTOR
```

And then in your code

```
class MyAPIHandler
{
   public:
       CONSTRUCTOR MyAPIHandler()
       {
           // Deep magic
       }
};
```

Now, by itself this will not do anything, but if you get used to writing it like this you should be able to spot the mistake more easily.

Although I honestly think that this is such a rare occurence that it isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: Not worth the trouble: Right.  Don't try to fix 'this issue' (which is very rare), rather try to fix the big picture (need better process for detecting bugs early).

Comment: I think that could just lull me into an even falser sense of security!
However, if C++ had an (optional) CONSTRUCTOR keyword...

Answer (score 0):

I guess following TDD will help, though not the solution you were looking for ...

as you said its legacy code, i suggest you read "working with legacy code- Kent Beck". That might help.

regression testing will pick issues due to bug fixes.

even i am looking forward for out of box suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests.

```
MyAPIHandler mah;
BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(mah.handle, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of broilerplates/templates (in Vim.. but I guess you can have them in any modern editor) which avoids typos of this nature.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDEs allow for macros of some sort. Just use a macro to create a class definition. That's the way I have it setup. My macro prints outs:

```
class CHANGETHIS
{
    public: 
      CHANGETHIS();
      ~CHANGETHIS();
}
#error "Finish this class definition"
```

The #error line is just a safety net to make sure it doesn't build if I am interrupted in the middle of my work and forget about it when I get back.

What I like about this is that its portable across any editor, so I don't feel handicapped when I switch to a different IDE. Hope this helps.

In addition, use initialization lists. They're faster and lead to less bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the simplest way of avoiding this problem is to lay down the law for naming in the form of a coding style guide. In this you set down how to name your entities and you stick to it.

Specifically at work we've got it mandatory that abbreviations are only capitalised on the first letter, therefore this would be caught more easily.